# Get file content as a Terraform output

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, systemd, iaas

I have a Terraform configuration where I start a systemd service on an AWS EC2 instance. I need to grep that service's log and export it to be a Terraform output.

When `hello.service` is started, it logs a line like this (among many other):

```
Root Key: F4BF9F7FCBEDABA0392F108C59D8F4A38B38
```

I need that line to be a Terraform output. Something like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {

    provisioner "remote-exec" {
        //start hello.service
    }

}

output "rootKey" {
    value = "${}" //??
}
```

I want `rootKey` output to be the result of:

`journalctl -u hello.service | grep "Root Key`"

being executed at `aws_instance.instance`

How can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be with the external data source and a wrapper script that does the `journalctl -u hello.service | grep "Root Key"` part to give you back the root key.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html

Comment: It seems that the program in external data sources is executed on the machine running terraform, is it? I need to be executed on the remote instance. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the github module created by Matti Paksula: https://github.com/matti/terraform-shell-resource

the repo has a good description and many examples to get started